# Select sem o campo id (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

estou com uma dúvida muito boba, estou fazendo um sisteminha com Ruby on Rails e preciso fazer um select onde não venha o campo id, o problema é que este campo sempre está presente, por exemplo: `Employee.select('nome, email').all`

O Código acima deveria retornar vários registros e trazer apenas os campos nome e email como estou configurando, assim como acontece com outros campos, porém o id fica nil, mas não desaparece, o registro fica parecido com isso:

```
{
  id: null,
  name: "CRISTINA EXEMPLO",
  email: "Executiva de Atendimento"
}
```

Como faço para remover esse campo de forma objetiva, pois sei que poderia iterar sobre o resultado e criar uma lista simples, porém acredito que o rails dê suporte a resolver isso sem grandes manobras.

Espero ter sido claro e aguardo uma ajudinha, vlw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alessandro, essa sua questão é complicada e exige que entendamos algumas coisas:

#### 1) Caso você queira retornar um objeto sem o atributo `id`, o Rails não fará isso, e te explico por quê:

Você criou uma classe, o model `ActiveRecord` que está implicitamente vinculada aos registros do banco. Como no Rails tudo é por convenção, ele admite que sua classe declara os atributos referentes aos campos da tabela a qual ela está vinculada. E sabemos que todo objeto gerado por uma classe deve respeitar seus métodos e atributos no qual a classe definiu. Portanto, se você cria(implicitamente) uma classe que possui o atributo `id`, como você poderia ter um objeto gerado por esta classe sem este atributo?

Se você quiser mesmo um objeto que contenha somente os atributos que lhe convém, você deveria encapsular este resultado em um outro objeto definido por uma nova classe (poderia ser um `Struct` ou `OpenStruct` mesmo). Ela faria o papel de um [DTO (Data Transfer Object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

#### 2) Caso você queira retornar um hash padrão, somente com estes campos:

Bem, aí você deve fazer um loop e montar o seu `Hash`, não tem jeito, porque o `Rails` como citado acima, vai sempre respeitar o contrato definido pela classe (implicitamente). Então, mesmo que você peça para ele retornar como um objeto `Hash`, ele irá se basear nos atributos do seu modelo.

#### Minha sugestão

Você querendo retornar um objeto do tipo `Hash` ou um outro objeto que você queira definir (opção 1), por que você não cria um método no seu modelo que faça isso para você. A iteração para se criar um Hash ou montar um objeto novo (poderia ser um `Struct`) é muito simples, e você não iria expor isto para o resto da aplicação. Algo como:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_with_fields_that_i_want
    all.map do |e|
      OpenStruct.new({name: e.name, email: e.email})
    end
  end
end

results = Employee.all_with_fields_that_i_want
```

Comment: Olá Rafael, obrigado pelo esclarecimento sobre a questão depois de tanto tempo. Já faz tanto tempo que postei quem nem lembrava mais dessa questão =D, de qualquer forma é sempre bom ter uma explicação bem objetiva e aprofundada sobre o problema.

Resolvi o problema de alguma forma que não me lembro no momento, mas sua resposta foi muito importante.

Comment: De nada, e que bom que resolveu! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.select('field AS field_one').first.field_one   
# => "value"
```

Verifiquei na documentação do método [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) veja se isso resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também usar o active record e fazer um map

```
Model.where(name: 'Cristina', email: 'teste@abc.com').map{|m| {name: m.name, email: m.email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o method except

> http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/except

#### Exemplo

```
Model.find(10).order('id asc').except(:id)
```

Ou então na hora de montar um .each você pode rejeitar um :campo

#### Exemplo

```
<% @model.reject(&:password_digest?).each do |attribute| %>
```